# How to print elements of an array by pointers?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  int a[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  int *p = &a[6];
  printf("%d\n", *p);
  printf("%d\n", *(p + 1));
}
```

I am trying to print the elements of an array with the help of the pointer but it is giving me an error. Please help me by having a look at the code above?

Comment: What are the valid indices for an array of 6 elements? What does that make `&a[6]`?

Comment: you accessing a[6] and index 6 is doesn't exist

Comment: What is *zero indexed* in C?

Answer (score 2):

you need something like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  int a[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  int *p = a;// storing base address
  printf("%d\n", *p);
  printf("%d\n", *(p + 1));
}
```

Comment: You may want to comment on `int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};` as being less prone to error, etc..

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason for this change?

Comment: You were accessing address of a[6] and the range of your array is from 0 to 5, that was giving you garbage value.